# Vertical centering of images in responsive design behaving differerent in WebKit

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I am currently building a responsive website which uses a brilliant script which vertically centers images within a parent with a max-height and overflow set to hidden:

http://demo.solemone.de/overflow-image-with-vertical-centering-for-responsive-web-design/

The script works perfectly when there is only one instance of the container on the page, however when one or more instances of the container are found the vertical centering is ruined. It seems the script applys the same margin to all of the images on the page which in my case isn't ideal considering:

1. The different instances of the container have different max-heights.
2. The images have different heights and therefore should have a unique margin.

In order to overcome the issues I was facing I slightly modified the script, using the jQuery .each() function to iterate over the objects and run the function. The results can be seen at the following URL:

http://www.lewismalpas.co.uk/rwd

This seems to work as intended and each image has a unique margin which is great, however I am eperiencing a few problems which I canonot solve and I would really appreciate your help. Firstly 
I am getting a JS error in the console which I cannot fix:

`ReferenceError: centerImage is not defined`

I am also getting unexpected results in Safari/Chrome as the images are not being centered vertically on page load or refresh however pressing return with the URL field seems to center the images but this isn't ideal.

Any help with these issues/inconcistencies would be really appreciated,

Thanks,

Lewis.

Answer (score 0):

--------- Sorry discard my answer, failed to read the full question --------------

Yes you're right. Just had a quick look at the code.

You might wna change the centerImage() function to something like this:

```
 function centerImage() {
   $container.each(function() { //iterate through every single container
      $this = $(this); // wrap the current container in jQuery so you can call some jQuery methods.
      $img = $this.find('img'); // finding the image inside current container.
      imageHeight = $img.height();
      wrapperHeight = $this.height();
      overlap = (wrapperHeight - innerHeight) / 2;
      $img.css('margin-top', overlap);
   });
 }
```

Everything else is fine.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Varinder, thanks for your answer - I presume you edited it as it wouldn't work for multiple instances of the container?